# Calculation of the heigth of the camera

Tags: focal-length, field-of-view, subject-distance

I am trying to find the height of a drone using the camera only. I can calculate the distance of the object top and bottom. Object is a square platform with width=0.2m. I used the equation provided by this article: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/

Now, i am writing  a program for a small drone, is there a way to calculate the height of it using the distances shown in the image below? The platform is always sitting straight as shown in the image.
FOV of the camera = 82.6 degrees

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about using a camera as a measuring device rather than to produce an artistic or documentary photograph as the end result.

Comment: Perhaps try at https://math.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your distances are accurate, you have two right triangles:

1. Drone, point on ground below drone (\$H\$), bottom corner of platform
2. Drone, point 20 cm above ground below drone (\$H-h\$), top corner of platform

Using Pythagoras theorem, with \$D\$ the distance between ground track of drone and platform:

$$\begin{align}
\text{eq. 1:} && H^2+D^2 &= (\mathrm{distance2})^2 \\
\text{eq. 2:} &&(H-h)^2+D^2 &= (\mathrm{distance1})^2
\end{align}$$

Subtracting eq. 2 from eq. 1:

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
2Hh - h^2 &= (\mathrm{distance2})^2 - (\mathrm{distance2})^2 \\
H &= \frac{(\mathrm{distance2})^2 - (\mathrm{distance2})^2 + h^2}{2h}
\end{align}$$

But I would be surprised if your distance were accurate enough.